# How to use SQL Server Table-Data type, in Delphi, using FireDAC?

Tags: sql-server, delphi

For example:

I have a data-table type in SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.typTable1 AS TABLE
(
    Field1 INT NOT NULL,
    Field2 NVARCHAR(20) NULL
)
```

And a stored procedure in SQL, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDRE dbo.prcTest
    @XDataTable dbo.typTable1 READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    .
    .
    .
```

And now problem!!! :
  When i send a table as parameter in delphi like this:

```
FireDACStoredProcedure.Params.ParamByName('@XDataTable').AsDataset := 
    FireDACMemTable;
```

And when i run this, an error accour that say not supported.

Please guide me...thanks to you so much...

Comment: Forget your Delphi code for a moment: can you successfully invoke your prcTest from a TransactSQL script in SSMS?

Comment: Please do not post fake code like "CREATE PROCEDRE".  Also is there any text missing before @XDataTable?

Comment: Hello dear MartinA...Sure...I will post entire code...thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking something like that:

```
Set the DataType = ftObject;

Set datatypename = <your_procedureName>.<your_parameter>

With FireDACStoredProcedure.Params.ParamByName('@XDataTable') do
begin
DataType := ftObject;
DataTypeName := 'prcTest.@XDataTable';
end;
```

Inspired in https://delphiaball.co.uk/2016/04/29/interbase-array-fields-firedac/

Comment: @Vahid Accept answer